How to set focus on an element when launching the app?
I would like to preselect one specific actionButton when the session opens. I set as default value that my actionButton "two" should be selected. However, I have not found a way to change the style of the button in a way that the button looks greyish (selected) when the session starts. I know that the style can be changed in general with style = "..." but then it doesn't go back to normal when another button is selected.
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton("one", "One"),
  actionButton("two", "Two"),
  actionButton("three", "Three"),
  textOutput("text")
)

server <- function(session, input, output) {
  
  v <- reactiveValues(data = 2)
  
  observeEvent(input$one, {
    v$data <- 1
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$two, { # this button should be preselected
    v$data <- 2
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$three, {
    v$data <- 3
  })
  
  output$text <- renderText({v$data})
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)

I would like the preselection to simply look like this:


A solution where the focus is set via js:
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(
    tags$script(
      HTML("
           $(document).ready(function() {
             $('#two').focus()
                      .css('outline', 'none');
           })
           ")
      )
  ),
  actionButton("one", "One"),
  actionButton("two", "Two"),
  actionButton("three", "Three"),
  textOutput("text")
)

server <- function(session, input, output) {
  
  v <- reactiveValues(data = 2)
  
  observeEvent(input$one, {
    v$data <- 1
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$two, { # this button should be preselected
    v$data <- 2
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$three, {
    v$data <- 3
  })
  
  output$text <- renderText({v$data})
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)


Thank you, works great! However, I'm actually using shinydashboards with a sidebar and tabItems and the preselection is only there when the document is loaded and disappears when I click on a tabItem. How should I change the JS in a way that the preselection appears when clicking on the tabItem?

Okay, so shall the preselection indeed appear only when you click on the tabItem or shall it be there after the document is loaded and remain when you click on a tabItem? I do not completely understand the requirement. You may also want to ask a follow-up question on this, you can also reference on this question there.
